# Use Azure Data Studio to see SQL Server from container

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, azure-data-studio

I'm developing an .NET Core application. I use docker following this tutorial : https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/

So, thanks to docker compose I have dockerized my application and my SQL Server.

[image]

Now, I want to see my Database using software as Azure Data Studio. But when I try, I can't connect to the DB

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi [Nemtecl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8002756/nemtecl) already tried adding the 1433 port number to Azure Data Studio field called Server?

Like this: `localhost:1433`